# Match Strings to Class Properties

Tags: c#

I need to match the properties of the [FixedFormatSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.powerpoint.conversion.fixedformatsettings_properties.aspx).  For example, I may have the strings "BitmapUnembeddableFonts" and "UsePdaA" in a string[].  If I wanted to loop through the string[], and set any matching property I find (as a string) to true (e.g. FixedFormatSettings.UsePdaA = true), how would I go about doing that?

Comment: how would you find the values to set to this properties? Besides `true` for `UsePdaA`

Comment: Maybe using Reflection? Not sure what's the exact question... What have you tried? It would be nice if you can show us at least some effort on your side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use next code as an example of setting properties by having a dictionary of names and their values.

```
var valuesToSet = new Dictionary<string, object> 
                  {
                        {"BitmapUnembeddableFonts", false}, 
                        {"UsePdaA", true}
                  };

var settings = new FixedFormatSettings();

var properties = settings.GetType()
                         .GetProperties()
                         .Where(p => p.CanWrite);

foreach (var property in properties)
{
    object valueToSet;
    if(valuesToSet.TryGetValue(property.Name, out valueToSet))
    {
        property.SetValue(settings, valueToSet);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(settings.BitmapUnembeddableFonts); //false
Console.WriteLine(settings.UsePdaA); //true
```